# Azure Query across multiple application insights while unioning all different types

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, kql

When querying from a particular application insights `appInsights1`, after I select the application insights `appInsights1` from **Azure Portal**, I can use `union * | where timestamp > ago(1h)` to query **all different types** of telemetry data within recent 1 hour. Sweet.

If I want to query cross the application insights `appInsights1` & `appInsights2`, I can do `union *, app('appInsights2').requests, app('appInsights2').traces | where timestamp > ago(1h)`.

But what i really wanna achieve here is to have something like, `union *, app('appInsights2').* | where timestamp > ago(1h)`, to query **all different types** of telemetry data from `appInsights2` as well. But **MS** doesn't allow `app('appInsights2').*` here. Not sure why, even `union *` is perfect ok. Anyway, is there a way i can do it, rather than list all types in a tedious long way, like `app('appInsights2').requests, app('appInsights2').traces, app('appInsights2').exceptions, ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Meir from the Azure Monitor product group.

I understand the need but we have limited support for "*" tables, especially when it comes to cross-app queries. These queries are very intensive in compute and IO, much more than queries that specify table names. This substantially intensify when more than one app/workspace is involved.

Our recommendation today is to funnel all your App Insights into one or few Log Analytics Workspaces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource
In this mode, the workspace may contain tens if not hundreds of tables, but you don't have to union across apps.

Thanks,
Meir